# What disadvantage would there be to making class properties dynamic from MySQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

Sorry if the question sounds confusing, probably haven't worded it the best, but here is an example;

Say we have a 'sales' table with various columns, and we wanted to make a sales class in php, I would traditionally approach it this way...

```
class Sale 
{
    public $id;
    public $userID;
    public $customerID;
    public $sale_net;
    public $sale_vat;
    public $sale_gross;
    public $duration;
    public $sale_date;
    public $end_date;

    private $table = "sales";
    private $pk = "id";

function __construct($saleID=NULL){
    if($saleID!=NULL){
        global $pdo;
        $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$this->table} WHERE {$this->pk} = ?");
        $stm->execute(array($saleID));
        if($stm->rowCount() > 0)
            {
            $data = $stm->fetchObject();
            $this->id = $saleID;
            $this->userID = $data->userID;
            $this->customerID = $data->customerID;
            $this->sale_net = $data->sale_net;
            $this->sale_vat = $data->sale_vat;
            $this->sale_gross = $data->sale_gross;
            $this->duration = $data->duration;
            $this->sale_date = $data->sale_date;
            $this->end_date = $data->end_date;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Now to the point, what would be the disadvantages of the following approach;

```
class Sale 
{
    private $table = "sales";
    private $pk = "id";

    function __construct($saleID=NULL){
        if($saleID!=NULL){
            global $pdo;
            $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$this->table} WHERE {$this->pk} = ?");
            $stm->execute(array($saleID));
            if($stm->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                $this->isValid = true;
                $data = $stm->fetchAll();
                $sale = $data[0];
                foreach ($sale as $property => $value) {
                    $this->$property = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I see one advantage being if columns are added to the sales table, I can access them immediately without modifying the class itself.

Comment: The object shouldn't necessarily mirror the database table (outside of an ORM model anyway); you *might*, for instance, want to have the order lines as part of your `Sale` object; which makes perfect sense... but they would be in a completely separate table to your order header data. Your PHP object should have the logical data structure for the application - not the underlying way the data is stored.

Comment: Having all the class methods as public also goes against one of the core concepts of OOP, [encapsulation](https://stackify.com/oop-concept-for-beginners-what-is-encapsulation/)

Comment: I do not see a disadvantage to the second choice; same result but less code than choice 1. Regardless of 1 or 2, I hope you never plan to rename your DB columns.

Comment: I agree with @CD001 because the `Sale` class seems better suited as an abstraction layer for the underlying data and not an exact mirror. Strive to make the class usable even if you have no knowledge of where the data originated.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: @CD001 Interesting, for me personally I find it confusing having different names for the same thing e.g sale_net is the column name in the DB but then to have `$this->saleValue = $db->sale_net` would confuse me later on when using the class as I'd be going to try and use `$saleClassInstance->sale_net`. And with regard to encapsulation, of course not all methods and properties would be public. Do you or @MonkeyZeus have any examples of how a good 'extraction layer' class would look like for this example, and what benefits they have?

Comment: What you have there is very close to Active Record Pattern. This is bigger in the Ruby community than PHP. There was a library I used for an ORM solution but it looks dated and not super maintained. It is here http://www.phpactiverecord.org/. As for advantage/disadvantages every pattern has them. Pick the one that works for the task at hand.

Comment: **abs**traction not extraction. `$this->saleValue = $db->sale_net` is precisely correct because this allows you to fetch data from a different datasource without causing errors in code which uses the `Sale` class.

Comment: The point is that your application should only talk to the *abstraction model* rather than the database or ORM... that talks to the data/ORM model(s) it needs to load itself. Outside of data propagation of the object you should never care what the database fields are called. e.g. `$sales = new Sale($id)` could instantiate a new `Sale` object with all the sales lines and so on, ready for the application to use; e.g. `foreach($sale->getProducts() as $product) { ... }`.

Comment: So, what you've got here *looks* like a data/ORM model; and the only thing that should ever talk to this is your Sale abstraction model... so this is the *only* place you'd ever use those database column names as the rest of the application would talk to the abstraction model. That's the theory anyway - it means if you ever need to change the database structure at all you'd only need to change small chunk of code in a couple of files rather than having to refactor method calls across the entire codebase.

Comment: Thank you for all the insightful information everyone! Certainly opened up my eyes to various programming concepts that I am sure to bear in mind when writing my next script